# Rsync ssh connection closed

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to send a file from client to server but I keep getting command not found with connection unexpectedly closed after typing in the users ssh password. I'm using another ssh port and ssh works by itself but this command will just error on me:

```
rsync -v -e 'ssh -p2123' /var/log/file.log user@server:/
```

Returns password, when typed:

```
rsync: Command not found.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I've gone over different variations of the command but can't seem to establish a connection. Is there a reason the server could be rejecting me or is it that the command syntax is just wrong?

Comment: Why do I feel like I'm running this from the wrong machine...

Comment: Is there a copy of rsync installed on the remote system? What directory is it installed in?

Comment: On my windows system under D:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin

Comment: Something to do with the user... changing user error goes away. Should be noted that the failing user is virtual.